# Maintain state of auto-generated check-boxes on page refresh

Tags: php

In one of my web page it's having number of auto-generated check-boxes with same name.
and this page refresh on regular interval.
On refresh checked items are erases(reset to unchecked).

How can i maintain state of selected check-boxes on refresh?

```
"<tr><td><input name='list[]' type='checkbox' id='list[]' value='$row[0]' /></td>";
```

I tried numerous way to get it work but because all check-boxes having same name nothing is working fine.!!

Can Anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Which numerous ways?

Comment: Did you try cookies? Webstorage?

Comment: `id='list[]'` this is just wrong...

Comment: @JNF - tried with some code jquery to maintain state of checkbox but it works only for individual checkbox not for all. I also used "autocomplete" property but doesnt worked.

Comment: @Zentoaku - id='list[]' is used on submit to execute sql statement for selected checkboxes. if i rename checkboxes then i need to do seperate code for each auto-generated inputs which is not feasible..:(

Comment: When you catch GET/POST from submitted form the only thing that matters is a name of the input. Id is just useless, not to mention: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name

Answer (score 0):

add checked="checked"

instead of:

```
<tr><td><input name='list[]' type='checkbox' id='list[]' value='$row[0]' /></td>;
```

it should be:

```
<tr><td><input name='list[]' type='checkbox' id='list[]' checked="checked" /></td>;
```

This will also work:

```
<tr><td><input name='list[]' type='checkbox' id='list[]' checked /></td>;
```

But according HTml5 spec You shuld use: checked="checked"

EDIT:

it should be:

```
$sCheckboxCode = "<tr><td><input name='list[]' type='checkbox' id='list[]' ".row[0] ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "" ." /></td>;"
```

Comment: this makes all check-boxes selected by default - but i want only maintain state of selected check-boxes not all get selected on refresh

Comment: I cant rename check boxes because Onsubmit it takes as an array and execute a SQL query for selected items. :(

Answer (score 0):

you maybe add if fucntion

```
<tr><td><input name='list[]' type='checkbox' id='list[]' 
 <?php if($checked==$row[0]) echo "checked";?> /></td>;
```

now you can checked

Comment: not working! it makes all check-box checked by default on load :(